# libgdx: texture bind in multiple screens

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a question regarding when texture bind occur.
I extend the `Game` class, and have several `Screen` classes for different menus and the game.
I don't dispose the screens when I switch between them, and store them as members inside the `Game` class.

Each screen has different texture loaded and drawn. My question is, when I show one of the screens, do also the other screens' (which were already shown at least once and were not disposed) textures are bound, although they are not in use in the current shown screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question at LibGDX forum.

[The topic](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=13921&p=61177#p61177)

> **From Tonielro:** *The answer is no. Each screen handles its own drawing in the render method. Another screen cannot render graphics for another.*